# Retain edit text cursor position using data binding in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-databinding

I have created a getter a setter for my building name and wish change the string to replace any characters that does not match with the regex expression. However in doing so, every time I enter an invalid character the edit text cursor/selection position changes to the beginning of the text. Hoe do I avoid this from happening?

```
private String buildingname="";
@Bindable
public String getBuildingname() {
    return this.buildingname;
}

public void setBuildingname(String buildingname) {
    if(!this.buildingname.equals(buildingname)) {
        this.buildingname = buildingname.replaceAll(alphanumericregex,"");
        this.pcr.notifyChange(this, com.tomtom.sangrahit.BR.buildingname);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setSelection` of `editText` AFTER you are setting new text

```
int position = myEditText.getSelectionStart();
myEditText.setText(myNewText);
myEditText.setSelection(position);
```

Comment: This wont help. if I have a text with three words and I currently editing the second then the cursor would always jump to end of the third word all the time. I need to know why this is behaving this way. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I don't know that.. but if you want it to be at the current position, then check the edited version of the answer

Comment: can you share the code where you are actually performing `setText` ?

Comment: No luck. This line is causing  the cursor to reset to the beginning 
 `buildingname.replaceAll(alphanumericregex,"") ` and your solution always sets it to the end. What I really need is that the cursor should always remain in the current position while typing. Modifying the setter is somewhat bringing it to the start of the edit text.

Comment: There isn't any code for the setText. data binding takes care of that :)